# LOCAL Temperature Gradient and Stress

Tags: thermodynamics, solid-state-physics, elasticity, stress-strain, thermoelectricity

I'm investigating the thermo-migration failure mechanism in nanoscale ICs interconnects. Typically, a nano wire under thermal stress suffers from material/mass migration or void nucleation if it experiences a large amount of tensile hydrostatic stress (e.g. $\sigma_{critical}=40MPa$ for copper).

It's known that a temperature change of $\Delta T$ with respect to a *base* or *reference* level produces a thermal strain:

$$\epsilon_T=\alpha \Delta T$$

where $\alpha$ is the coefficient of thermal dilatation (i.e. thermal expansion coefficient). Thus stress can be obtained by $\sigma=E\epsilon$.

In my system, which is a nanoscale copper wire (e.g. $T=64nm$, $W=32nm$ and $L=2um$), temperature distribution is not linear as it is shown in the following figures:

[image: Wire]
[image: Temperature Distribution]

In other words, while the $\Delta T_{max}$ is around $5K$, the temperature gradient in some local regions (e.g. corners) can be up to $10K/\mu m$. The following figure shows the temperature gradient of one particular distribution, in which the gradients are very large at the end of the wire where it connects to other wires.

[image]

It has been experimentally reported that in a presence of a large **local** gradient in temperature (even with a small $\Delta T_{max}$), failure might happen (i.e. mass transports and void nucleates as it's shown in the following figure).

[image]

It can be seen that this phenomenon cannot be explained directly by $\epsilon_T=\alpha \Delta T$. I'm wondering how this large local gradient of temperature can be related to strain/stress properly. Because, as I mentioned above, the thermo-migration mortality of a wire is judged based on the critical hydro-static stress. Simply speaking, I'm hoping to find a relationship like:

$$\epsilon_T = \beta \nabla T$$

PS Can I simply conclude that: $\nabla \sigma = \alpha E \nabla T$?